# Does the image of the cosmic microwave background radiation show us what the universe used to look like?

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background

Is it possible to interpolate using the cosmic microwave background radiation and currently what we can see in the sky at night to predict what the night sky will look like in the future? I’m guessing the night sky will be increasingly bright regardless of light pollution on earths because more light from galaxies will reach us in more time?  If we can interpolate forwards, would we be also to interpolate backwards?

From my understanding, the cosmic microwave background radiation is what the universe used to look like.

Comment: With the naked eye, we can only see our near neighbour galaxies: the Magellanic Clouds, Andromeda, and the Triangulum galaxy. And that's only in areas of low light pollution. We won't see light from more galaxies in the future. The Milky Way will (probably) collide with Andromeda in a few billion years, but Earth will be uninhabitable by then. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_far_future

Comment: Additionally expansion causes dilution even if new objects enter our observable universe (which by the way does not mean *seen*).

Comment: Can you relate more clearly to something particular. CMBR means a lot of things all together.